# How to get substring in SQLsever by finding nth occurance of character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `varchar` field in **SQL Server 2008** like

`colName_vch = 'field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7'`

I want the value of **field4**.

Now one long way is to do use `RIGHT`,`CHARINDEX` for `;` and `SUBSTRING` in recursion, but that becomes very complex and increases query time.

Is there any other quick/less complex way for achieving this?

I know this is a bad DB design, but I am stuck with this for a while now.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You want `field4` because it is the 4th item physically in the list, not because it is 4th alphabetically, right?

Comment: yes, fourth item in the list

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i've really understood your question, but here is my guess:

You could write a custom `Split` function which splits by a delimiter(in this case `;`). Then you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the desired part with a given index(4 here).

For example:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100); 
SET @string='field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7'; 
DECLARE @index INT; 
SET @index = 4; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT item, 
                rn=Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       ORDER BY item) 
         FROM   dbo.Split(@string, ';')) 
SELECT TOP 1 item 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = @index
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ab19/8/0) on sql-fiddle.

This is my  split-function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: But using `ORDER BY Item` to determine row number will pick the 4th item alphabetically. In this case it just *happens* to be the case that the 4th item in the list *physically* is also the 4th *alphabetically*.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Maybe it is what OP actually wants. However, actually i've already notices this problem. But since i was not sure how to order by a not available index, i've asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294610/order-by-index-possible You are cordially invited to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE([Index] INT IDENTITY(1,1), Item NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @t(Item) SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ORDER BY Number OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    RETURN;
END
GO

DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT, string NVARCHAR(4000));

INSERT @x SELECT 1, N'field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, N'x;y;6;r;3;2;w;'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, N'ttt;444;rrr;333;111;444;777;888;';

SELECT x.i, s1.Item
FROM @x AS x
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(x.string, ';') AS s1
WHERE s1.[Index] = 4;
```