# Identify nth item when splitting a list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to provide a `ROW_NUMBER` in a cte be able to pick a specific item out of a sequence with a given index(like an array-indexer `arr[index]`). Of course the "sequence" is a table which comes from a table-valued-function(`Split`).

So how can I create an index when it's not available? This is the query:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100); 
SET @string='field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7'; 
DECLARE @index INT; 
SET @index = 4; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT item, 
                rn=Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       ORDER BY item) 
         FROM   dbo.Split(@string, ';')) 
SELECT TOP 1 item 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = @index
```

`Row_number()  OVER(ORDER BY item)` orders alphabetically but actually I want to order by a (not available) index.

Note that this question arised on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294380/284240) on [this so-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294211/how-to-get-substring-in-sqlsever-by-finding-nth-occurance-of-character).

Comment: Seems like something you would want to do within the Split function...have a field that returns the index

Comment: https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/04/21/geracao-de-sequencias-numericas/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you just need to keep track of where in the list each item appears. One way to do that is to have your split function insert with an `IDENTITY` column. Taking [my answer from the question you reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294672/61305):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS @t TABLE([Index] INT IDENTITY(1,1), Item NVARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT @t(Item) SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ORDER BY Number OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

    RETURN;
END
GO

DECLARE @x TABLE(i INT, string NVARCHAR(4000));

INSERT @x SELECT 1, N'field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;'
UNION ALL SELECT 2, N'x;y;6;r;3;2;w;'
UNION ALL SELECT 3, N'ttt;444;rrr;333;111;444;777;888;';

SELECT x.i, s1.Item
FROM @x AS x
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(x.string, ';') AS s1
WHERE s1.[Index] = 4;
```

An inline alternative, which *might* be *slightly* friendlier at scale:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
    WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

Of course ultimately you'll want to fix the schema. If the 4th element in this list is an important piece of data, you should be storing it separately.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I've seen already your answer on the other question. But what if i cannot change `dbo.Split`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter create `dbo.SplitOrdered`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `SELECT FROM dbo.Split` without an `ORDER BY` isn't guaranteed to return the results in any particular order.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You could use `ORDER BY charindex(';'+item+';', ';'+@string+';')) `

Comment: @Mikael and Martin I don't think the question is about returning the items in any specific order, it's about identifying a specific item (like the 4th item).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, I meant he should use the `order by` statement in in the `over()` clause. `rn` will then hold the position in the string. (Provided that the values in `@string` is unique).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - But this is clearly impossible based on the definition of `dbo.Split` that only returns an `item` column except if you believe that the results are output in that order hence relevance of comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the values in your string is unique you can use `ORDER BY charindex(';'+item+';', ';'+@string+';')` in the `OVER()` clause.

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100); 
SET @string='field1;field2;field3;field4;field5;field6;field7'; 
DECLARE @index INT; 
SET @index = 4; 

WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT item, 
                rn=Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       ORDER BY charindex(';'+item+';', ';'+@string+';')) 
         FROM   dbo.Split(@string, ';')) 
SELECT TOP 1 item 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = @index
```

`charindex` returns the position in `@string` for each extracted `item` so `rn` is generated according to position in `@string`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e5ce/1)

Comment: +1 clever, but seems cleaner (and much more intuitive, to me at least) to change the function (or add a dedicated one).

Comment: @AaronBertrand absolutely.