# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, substring

Following is my query and it works fine when I have like  TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL **'testing ~ testing, test ~ testq,'**  ends with comma but can't handle **'testing ~ testing, test ~ testq'** same as for other variable TRAILER_IDV.  I tried my best but cant work it out any help would be appreciated.
My aim is to get the comma separated value for xml.

```
DECLARE @TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TRAILER_IDV VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @USER_TYPE VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @START_INDEX_1 INT
DECLARE @START_INDEX_4 INT

DECLARE @END_INDEX_1 INT
DECLARE @END_INDEX_4 INT

DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
set @TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL='testing ~ testing, test ~ testq,' 
set @TRAILER_IDV='3500, 3400,'
set @USER_TYPE='MOBILE'

 set @QUERY = ''

set @START_INDEX_1 = 1
set @START_INDEX_4 = 1
set @END_INDEX_1 = 0
if ISNULL(@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL,'') <> ''
begin
 WHILE @START_INDEX_1 > 0 and @START_INDEX_1 < len(@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL)
BEGIN
SET @END_INDEX_1 = CHARINDEX(',',@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL,@START_INDEX_1)
if @END_INDEX_1 = 0 and @START_INDEX_1 = 1
Begin
    SET @END_INDEX_1 = len(@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL)
END 
if @USER_TYPE <> 'MOBILE'
Begin 
    SET @END_INDEX_1 = @END_INDEX_1 +1
End
SET @VALUE = SUBSTRING(@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL,@START_INDEX_1,@END_INDEX_1 - @START_INDEX_1)
SET @QUERY = @QUERY + 'UNION ALL SELECT ''' + @VALUE + ''' TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL'


SET @END_INDEX_4 = CHARINDEX(',',@TRAILER_IDV,@START_INDEX_4)
if @END_INDEX_4 = 0 and @START_INDEX_4 = 1
Begin
    SET @END_INDEX_4 = len(@TRAILER_IDV)
END
if @USER_TYPE <> 'MOBILE'
Begin 
    SET @END_INDEX_4 = @END_INDEX_4 +1
End
SET @VALUE = SUBSTRING(@TRAILER_IDV,@START_INDEX_4,@END_INDEX_4 - @START_INDEX_4)
SET @QUERY = @QUERY + ',' + @VALUE + 'TRAILER_IDV '
print @QUERY
SET @START_INDEX_1 = @END_INDEX_1 + 1   
SET @START_INDEX_4 = @END_INDEX_4 + 1

END
select @QUERY=substring(@QUERY, 10, LEN(@QUERY) - 9)
EXEC (@QUERY) 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have a lot of code here so two extra lines where you assign a comma at the end of each string should probably not slow things down for you or make the code less maintainable.

```
SET @TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL += ',';
SET @TRAILER_IDV += ',';
```

I don't really understand what your code does but to get the result you are getting you can use a [split string function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294723/569436) that returns the index of the item like this.

```
select T1.Item as TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL,
       T2.Item as TRAILER_IDV
from dbo.SplitString(@TRAILER_MAKE_MODEL, ',') as T1
  inner join dbo.SplitString(@TRAILER_IDV, ',') as T2
    on T1.ItemNumber = T2.ItemNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.I'm a beginner and I cannot assure how many ',' separated values I will have in the variable So I have to split all of them.

Comment: @Gops The number of commas is no issue unless you have a lot of them. Then it may take some time to split the strings.